# Cannot get the right image source from a <div> tag using PHP Simple DOM

Tags: php

I am trying to get the image source info using the div element of an image. However when I debug the result the source of the image is different, Here is my DOM tree:

[image]

Here is the url for a reference: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Front-strut-spacers-30mm-for-Ford-FOCUS-2-3-C-MAX-KUGA-GRAND-C-MAX-Lift-Kit/192539735653?hash=item2cd4433665:g:4LMAAOSwHPNa-TOF

This is my php code:

```
            $img = $html->find("#viEnlargeImgLayer_img_ctr", 0);
            print($img);
            if($img != null){
              $item['img'] = $img->getAttribute('src');

            }else{
                $item['img'] = '';
            }
```

This is the result when I output the `img` tag:
[image]

As you can see there is a discrepancy in the image sources in the website and in my result. Does anybody know what can cause this? My goal is to get this link from the first screenshot: https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/M1cAAOSw9Ypa-TOF/s-l1600.jpg

Comment: look at the page source code ( not via the console ) - the image you reference is a simple placeholder GIF which is replaced by Javascript. You need to use a `headless` browser to scrape content from fleeBay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like viEnlargeImgLayer_img_ctr is a placeholder div that gets replaced with javascript. i've found that `$html->find("#icImg", 0);` will return the correct image

Comment: Thank you. I saw it the `div` in the inspector and will know how to find these images for now onwards. Thank you very much!